# Using Retrofit API With Android 2.2

Tags: retrofit, androidhttpclient

I have to build an android application that accesses a php script that echoes json.
I migrated to android studio,targeted andoid sdk 22 (5.0),had a minimum 
sdk of 8(Froyo) and built the project.

The snag occurred  where my past code that i used on eclipse
to launch "httppost" requests where not working.

The logcat showed an "unknown host exception" for the urls that where
passed as strings.

When i changed from "defaulthttpclient" to "httpurlconnection"
it worked,but the connection was too slow. (On android 2.2)

I read about the "Retrofit" api as a good library for fast http requests,
but i read two conflicting reports:

```
     The minimum sdk for retrofit is android 2.3
```

And then

```
  Retrofit uses httpurlconnection on android 2.3+ and httpclient on androd 2.2
```

This has me a bit confused. So the real question is

```
  Can retrofit handle my http requests on an android 2.2 phone?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you have to run retrofit with pre2.0 okhttp, urlconnection or apache client.

Latest versions of the okhttp require Java7 or android 2.3+

https://square.github.io/retrofit/#download

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/826

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/528#issuecomment-96622594